# How to change the color of the order status action buttons in the order preview?

Tags: css, woocommerce

How do I change the color of the order status action buttons in the modal window that displays when I click on the 'eye' icon in the WooCommerce order overview?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a little bit of CSS to that specific page via the following action:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', 'order_list_custom_action_buttons_color' );
function order_list_custom_action_buttons_color() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {
        ?>
        <style>
            a.wc-action-button-complete {
                background: lightgreen!important;
                color: floralwhite!important;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Simply add styles for each button.

Comment: Thanks Terminator-Barbapapa for your help. It worked perfectly.

Comment: If this answer worked for you please mark it as accepted.